# Android libVLC - way to clear the surface after stopping playback

Tags: android, surfaceview, libvlc

With [vlc-android](https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android), I have the following snippet in a fragment:

```
private LibVLC mLibVLC;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private VLCVideoLayout mVideoLayout;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mVideoLayout = inflate.findViewById(R.id.video_layout);
    mMediaPlayer.attachViews(mVideoLayout, null, true, false);

    return inflate;
}

public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLibVLC = new LibVLC(getActivity(), args);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mLibVLC);
}

public void playStream(String stream) {
    mMediaPlayer.play(Uri.parse(stream));
}

public void stopStream() {
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
}
```

This code is based on the official [libvlc-android-samples](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples).

All works fine, it can play whatever I want by passing it to *playStream*.

When I call the *stopStream* function, the playback stops but the surface stays there and it is not cleared. I.e. mVideoLayout contains the last decoded frame.

### Is there a way to clear this frame and set it to black?

**I want to reuse this player to play something else using the *playStream* again.**

What I have already tried:

- mMediaPlayer.detachViews() -> does not clear the frame
- mVideoLayout.removeAllViews() -> clears the frame, but the next play action crashes (also if I call attachViews() again)
- make the mVideoLayout invisible, then visible once the stream actually starts -> for some short time in the beginning of the new stream, the surface displays the old one

During the media change the fragment will be visible, solutions with fragment transactions are not applicable for me now.

Answer (score 0):

try to detach view after stopping streaming :

```
mMediaPlayer.getVLCVout().detachViews();
```

Good luck,

Comment: Unfortunately it results the same as *mMediaPlayer.detachViews()*. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if any one need answer this question you should store all layout Child

```
 for (int i = 0; i <  vlcVideoLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = vlcVideoLayout.getChildAt(i);
        viewArrayList.add(v);
    }
```

then you should use

```
   vlcVideoLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
```

to reuse this player to play something else you should add the array to vlcVideoLayout